# We have $\forall k \in[|1,p-1 |],\quad k\wedge p =1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $p \in \mathcal{P}$, then p is prime with all integers that it does not divide. In particular, if p is a prime number, we have:
>   $$\forall k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\},\quad  k\wedge p =1$$

**Notation :**

$\mathcal{P}:=$ set of positive prime numbers

$\wedge$:=gcd (Greatest common divisor)

$[|1,p-1|]:=   \{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$

**Reference:**
[image]

My question:

If P is a prime number have we :

$$\forall k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\} \iff p \nmid k$$

Comment: That's exactly what $\iff$ means. The expression $$\forall k \in [|1,p-1 |] \iff p \nmid k$$ means that (for all $k$,) $k\in[|1,p-1|]$ is equivalent to $p\not\mid k$.

Comment: That's my question if p is prime number  have we$$ \forall k \in [|1,p-1 |] \iff p \nmid k$$

Comment: Doesn't your reference say anything useful about it? Also, if $k\in[|1,p-1|]$ means that $\gcd(p,k)=1$ then it's clear that $p\nmid k$ (since otherwise $\gcd(p,k)=p$) and if $\gcd(p,k)\neq1$, then the only other option for that gcd is $p$ (since $1$ and $p$ are $p$'s only divisors) and so $\gcd(p,k)=p$ meaning $p\mid k$.

Comment: my reference say nothing about it but thank you for ur help

Comment: $[|1,p-1 |]$ is non-standard notation, so you might want to define it. Presumably, it is $\{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $\forall k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\} \iff p \nmid k$ doesn't really make sense "grammatically", but presumably you mean $\forall k (k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\} \iff p \nmid k)$. This statement is false, as you can see by taking $k=p+1$ or $k=-1$ or....

The statement $\forall k\in[\![1,p-1]\!] \; k\wedge p=1$ is shorthand for $\forall k (k\in[\![1,p-1]\!] \implies k\wedge p=1)$, which is intrinsically a one-way implication.

Since you are wondering about the implication $\forall k (k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\} \implies p \nmid k)$: this is a true implication. Hopefully you have seen somewhere before that if $a$ and $b$ are both positive integers, and $a$ divides $b$, then $a \le b$. The contrapositive of this statement is: for positive integers $a$ and $b$, if $a > b$, then $a \nmid b$. You can now apply this with $a=p$ and with any $k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations but as you see the author of the textbook showed the general case ie "p is prime with all integers it does not divide" I wonder how it went from the general case to the particular case  $k \in k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$  It is because I wonder if there exists a relation between $k \in \{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ and $p\nmid k$

Comment: I've augmented my answer accordingly.

Comment: could you please  suggest some good reference which talk about the same subject